# Jquery - Deactivate FF4 Browser-Resize function

Tags: jquery, firefox, resize

the new FF4 browser has an own textarea resize function.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/

Is there a way to deactivate (with js/jquery/css) this feature?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use css property

```
resize: none;
```

here is the Demo
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hPzW/)